# Is it possible to declare a variable inside of the "if" condition in Kotlin?

Tags: if-statement, variables, kotlin, optimization

I have this line of code:

```
if (x * y * z > maxProduct) maxProduct = x * y * z
```

But my problem is that I have to write `x * y * z` two times when I want to use it like this. I know I could create a variable before the `if` statement, like this:

```
val product = x * y * z
if (product > maxProduct) maxProduct = product
```

But I don't like that I have to create a temporary variable that's used just for this expression. Is there a way to improve my code?

Comment: You might be able to do it with `when(val` but the end result won't be better. I'd just create the val.

Comment: Also, you can use `(x * y * z).let { … }` or `(x * y * z).run { … }` (`with(x * y * z) { … }`). Or for your code snippet specifically you can just use `maxProduct = max(maxProduct, x * y * z)`.

Comment: You can do it differently, but doing so, you won't improve performance or readability...

Comment: `maxProduct = max(maxProduct, x* y *z)` is the most simplest

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
maxProduct = maxProduct.coerceAtLeast(x * y * z)
```

or

```
maxProduct = max(maxProduct, x * y * z)
```

More generally (for expressions that don't have a shortcut function), `.let()` can be used to avoid the separate variable. But when you squeeze it on one line, in my opinion it's not as easy to read:

```
(x * y * z).let { if (it > maxProduct) maxProduct = it }
```

Answer (score 7):

There is no good improvement for your requirement. But if you want some functional style code without creating a new variable use something like this:

```
(x * y * z).takeIf { it > maxProduct }?.let { maxProduct = it }
```

It is less readable, so I would suggest to stick with an additional variable.

Comment: Seems to meet the requirements of this question, but is a lot less readable (to me) ;-)